# Why is BsonDocument.Parse deserialize the wrong decimal128

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this link with a query string:

```
https://.../monsters/find?query={"battery_life": 2.4}
```

this method in the controller:

```
    [HttpGet("find")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllByCriteria([FromQuery(Name = "query")]string query)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            BsonDocument q = BsonDocument.Parse(query);


            var result = await _monsterService.GetAll(q);

            return Ok(result);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

and the model battery_life field is:

```
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Decimal128)]
    public decimal BatteryLife { get; set; }
```

I'm asking a battery life equal to 2.4 but when I debug with Postman, after the BsonDocument.Parse I get :

[image]

Why is that happening and what is the solution.

thx

**Update**

What I see from the debugger is that battery_life type is string. The value (2.4) type is ? =>

[image]

Comment: Here what do you mean by the wrong decimal128? What is your expected result?

Comment: I'm asking for a list of object with battery_life of 2.4 and it end up searching for a battery_life of 2.399999999.

Comment: Where does you model comes into play? All I see is the BsonDocument class which may have the value deserialized as a double by default – thus normal floating point shenanigans ensue. What happens when you expand q in the debugger? What type does it show for `battery_life`?

Comment: When I create a new object, I want the battery_life to be a decimal type instead of a string. I update my question with a new image from the debugger

Comment: Read what you were actually told already. `BsonDocument.parse()` does not know anything about your class definition. It just sees `2.4` and presumes "double". You actually need to marshal you "JSON String" into a `decimal` manually. Either that or leave the value as a "string" i.e `"2.4"` as a BsonDocument which *should* be detected on mapping for the `GetAll()` and cast as `Decimal128`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, @ckuri was right saying that is deserialized as a double by default. So what happened is whene I create a new object with battery_life type as decimal128 is it saved as decimal128. Can see it with MongoDB compass here:

[image]

when I was trying to query it was looking the field battery_life with double as type, it wasn't there so it returns an empty array.

When I changed the type manually for double and retry the query it works.
So from now, I'll change my object field battery_life type for

```
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double)]
    public double BatteryLife { get; set; }
```

Thanks to you guys, I just learned a little bit more!